# Iphone/Jqtouch Testing without iphone

Tags: iphone, jqtouch

I am developing web application using jqtouch. But I don't have iphone/ipod touch. what is the best way to test html generated out of it with jqtouch.

Thanks
coool

Comment: I am on window vista and found MobiOne to be good for testing IPhone UI. Thanks for all your answers....

Answer (score 1):

Download and install XCode from the Apple website.
It includes an iPhone/iPad simulator, with Safari, that you can run on your system.

Comment: Yup. But be sure you know that the simulator generally runs *much* faster than an actual device.

Comment: Yep, and it does not have a full gestures support... But this is still the best way, AFAIK... (except buying a real iPhone, of course) ; )

Answer (score 0):

If you develop on MacOS, use iPhone emulator otherwise use Safari.